# A good VML tutorial / reference

Tags: internet-explorer, vml

Has anybody here come across a good tutorial or a reference on VML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How about The W3C's official tutorial?](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-VML) It get's really in-depth (no joke, it's [90.96 KB](http://bytesizematters.com/) (not counting images))  and it can be your complete reference.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's [VML Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb263898(VS.85).aspx) is here.

Lucas is right, the [submission to the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/NOTE-VML) is good too.

Comment: Just a reminder, there is sight difference between MS VML Reference and W3C submission.